# Insert date to datetime type column

Tags: java, mysql

I want to insert a date to a mysql database table. The datatype of the related column in mysql 
database table is datetime. I used the following code.

```
String date="2013.05.15";
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(Long.parseLong(date));
```

when I am inserting timestamp value, it throws numberformat exception. Anybody please tell me
how to insert the value to the database.
Thank You .

Comment: @JqueryLearner Compiles is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not parsing the date correctly. Actually you're trying to 
parse it as long which is a number, not a date. You can use this code.

```
    String date="2013.05.15";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
    Date dt = sdf.parse(date);
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(dt.getTime());
```

Comment: It adds date with time.(2013-05-15 00:00:00) I want to remove time. Can you please help me?

Comment: If it's a datetime column, then that's just how dates are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `NOW()` function of mysql or use timestamp to insert into mysql.

and make sure datatype of mysql field `datetime`

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
Timestamp dateForDb= timestamp;
```

insert `dateForDb` into your database.